# Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1 when deploying my client site to Vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, react-dom

When am I trying to deploying my website on vercel. I am getting this error

`Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1 Cloning github.com/sachinsingh4/codeBlog (Branch: main, Commit: e5dd20b) Previous build cache not available Cloning completed: 914.884ms Running "vercel build" Vercel CLI 28.16.6 Installing dependencies... yarn install v1.22.17 warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json. [1/4] Resolving packages... warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2. [2/4] Fetching packages... [3/4] Linking dependencies... warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4". warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta". [4/4] Building fresh packages... success Saved lockfile. Done in 28.18s. Running "yarn run build" yarn run v1.22.17 $ react-scripts build Creating an optimized production build... Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19) at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10) at module.exports (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53) at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16) at handleParseError (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10) at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5 at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12 at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3 at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10) at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10) at runSyncOrAsync (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11) at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2) at Array.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4) at Storage.finished (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16) at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9 /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19 throw err; ^ Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19) at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10) at module.exports (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53) at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16) at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10 at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13 at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11 at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18 at context.callback (/vercel/path0/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13) at /vercel/path0/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 { opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ], library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' } Node.js v18.12.1 error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command. Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Seems like you have installed packages using npm and building using yarn. try `npm run build`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your yarn.lock and node_modules,try npm install and npm run build